# Regex negative lookahead (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have tried multiple things and read currently available blogs, but no luck

I want to detect just

```
1. pavneet
2. pavnet
```

But not

```
1. pavneet's name
2. pavnet's name
3. pavneet name
4. pavnet's name
```

(want to add name as -ve lookahead even after 's)

So far I have tried this https://regex101.com/r/8SUCMQ/1

```
(pavneet|pavne{1,2}t)\'?s?(?!\ *name)
```

Comment: `^pavne{1,2}t$`? See https://regex101.com/r/8SUCMQ/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `'s` in the lookahead and make it optional.

Also you could write `(pavneet|pavne{1,2}t)` as `pavnee?t`

```
\bpavnee?t(?!(?:'s)? name\b)
```

- `\bpavnee?t` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, match `pavnet` or `pavneet`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:'s)?`  Optionally match `'s` and a space
  - `name\b` Match `name` and a word boundary
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6XxMw3/1)